# Use a vector from an R markdown code chunk in a LaTeX environment (pmatrix)?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I want to create a column vector in R markdown from a variable in a code chunk.  Namely, I want to use the `\begin{pmatrix}` environment.  But in LaTeX, each element of the vector is separated by a newline `\\`.  The code in LaTeX would be as follows:

`\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}`.

I want it to produce the following:
[column vector with parentheses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnqS9.jpg)
where x_1, x_2, and x_3 are the elements of a numeric vector in an R code chunk.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  have R create the LaTeX code, and put it in a chunk with `results = 'asis'`, or you can use inline R code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Gregor"
date: "December 5, 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
x = 1:3
cat("$$ \\begin{pmatrix}", paste(x, collapse = " \\\\ "), "\\end{pmatrix} $$", sep = " ")
```

Or inline code:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
`r x[1]` \\ `r x[2]` \\ `r x[3]`
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Alternately

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
`r  paste(x, collapse = " \\\\ ")`
\end{pmatrix}
$$
````

Yielding:

[image]

If you're doing this a lot, you could easily make a little convenience function, possibly even [a hook](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/), depending how you want to use it.

Comment: Your third example is exactly what I was looking for—a method that easily generalizes to any size without additional code.